# How to know programatically if current page is homepage in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is there an easy way to programmatically know if the current page is a site homepage from a webpart code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found the answer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontextpageinfo.iswebwelcomepage.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this post might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649833/replace-the-default-page-in-a-sharepoint-website

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need to replace the default page. I only need to know if the current page is the "homepage" of the site.

Comment: @emzero, The post I am referring to explains how to programmatically see which page is the default: either `PublishingWeb.DefaultPage` if it's a publishing web, or `rootFolder.WelcomePage` if it is a simple web. What you have to do is compare the current page url to these two values.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you permit the homepage to *tell* your web part that it is a homepage. Add a parameter to the web part and allow it to be set in the Edit dialog.

Comment: The thing is that the webpart is added (static) right into the masterpage (this is a requirement, it cannot be done in other way).

Comment: Please update your question with this information. I've never heard of placing a web part into a master page, and I may not be the only one who hasn't heard of that.

Comment: apparently there are people who do so: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/09/add-web-part-inside-master-page-in-moss.html Sounds to be technically possible, but I wouldn't want to try out :-)

Comment: Adding webparts to master page is not the topic of this question. You can google about it, it's possible. You can't add Web part zones to master pages, you can only add statics web parts.

Comment: @emzero: I still suspect that you might get a better answer if you update your question to include this information. Most people will be thinking about "normal" web parts.